# Three.js imported collada model - change materials on different parts

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, collada

I am new to three.js and struggling with the concept of changing materials using code. I have got a model of a car, and I want to change the colour of the body to one shader material and change the windows to another, etc. Is this possible? If so, could somebody please explain how in relatively simple terms? 
I have pasted my current code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<title>Test WebGL</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">

<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>


 <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
void main() {
vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">
uniform vec3 topColor;
uniform vec3 bottomColor;
uniform float offset;
uniform float exponent;
varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
void main() {
float h = normalize( vWorldPosition + offset ).y;
gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( bottomColor, topColor, max( pow( h, exponent 
), 0.0 ) ), 1.0 );
}
</script>



<script>
var scene, camera, renderer;
init();
animate();
function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.set(100,100,100);
scene.add(camera);
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});


var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent;
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 
'fragmentShader').textContent;
var uniforms = {
topColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x171717) },
bottomColor: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xcbcbcb ) },
offset: { type: "f", value: 100 },
exponent:   { type: "f", value: 0.7 }
}
var skyGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2000, 32, 15 );
var skyMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { vertexShader: vertexShader,
fragmentShader: fragmentShader, uniforms: uniforms, side: 
THREE.BackSide } );
var sky = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeo, skyMat );
scene.add( sky );


var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xfffff3, 0.8);
light.position.set(-100,200,100);
scene.add(light);
var sphereSize = 1;
var pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( light, sphereSize );
scene.add( pointLightHelper );
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xd7f0ff, 0.2);
light2.position.set(200,200,100);
scene.add(light2);
var sphereSize = 1;
var pointLightHelper2 = new THREE.PointLightHelper( light2, sphereSize );
scene.add( pointLightHelper2 );
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);
light3.position.set(150,200,-100);
scene.add(light3);
var sphereSize = 1;
var pointLightHelper3 = new THREE.PointLightHelper( light3, sphereSize );
scene.add( pointLightHelper3 );
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( 'models/Mini.dae', function ( collada ) {
//Mustang.dae
var dae = collada.scene;
var skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];
dae.position.set(0,0,0);//x,z,y- if you think in blender dimensions ;)
dae.scale.set(0.7,0.7,0.7);
scene.add(dae);
var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(50);
axes.position = dae.position;
scene.add(axes);
var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
gridXZ.setColors( new THREE.Color(0x8f8f8f), new THREE.Color(0x8f8f8f) );
gridXZ.position.set(0,0,0 );
scene.add(gridXZ);
});
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
}
function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
controls.update();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```